# How to get data from input form

Tags: python, django, forms

I need to get data from input and write it to `query` variable. When I click to search button I need write data in query variable. How can I do that? I mean click event and write data in `query`.

This is my code:

`views.py:`

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import render

def index(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        return render(request, 'index.html', context={})

    # Handles the search once the submit button in the form is pressed
    # which sends a "POST" request
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # Get the input data from the POST request
        search_query = request.POST.get('search', None)

        # Validate input data
        if search_query and search_query != "":
            try: 
                from googlesearch import search 
            except ImportError:  
                print("No module named 'google' found")

            for j in search(search_query, tld="co.in", num=10, stop=1, pause=2): 
                print(j)
        else:
            return HttpResponse('Invalid input.')
```

`index.html:`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
</head>
<body>
    <form method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <input type="text" name="search" placeholder="some text"><br>
        <button class="button" name="submit" type="submit">Search</button>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

`urls.py`

```
from django.urls import path
from firstapp import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='home')
]
```

All files are in `hello` folder. My app namely `firstapp` `path:` `C:\Users\user\Desktop\hello\firstapp`

`index.html` path is:

`C:\Users\user\Desktop\hello\firstapp\templates`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We will need to change the `index()` function to handle `POST` or `GET` methods (refer to https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_httpmethods.asp for more information on `GET` and `POST` requests), by default django always listens to a `GET` request. You can know whether or not a method is `GET` by using `request.method == 'GET'` and `request.method == 'POST'` for `POST`.

To access the data inside the method, use `request.POST.get("search", None)`, which basically says find the input with the `name` attribute from the form or if the input does not exist, return `None`.

So, all in all, your code should now look like this

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import render


def index(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        return render(request, 'home/home.html', context={})

    # Handles the search once the submit button in the form is pressed
    # which sends a "POST" request
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # Get the input data from the POST request
        search_query = request.POST.get('search', None)

        # Validate input data
        if search_query and search_query != "":
            # Implement search functionality....
            # ...
            return HttpResponse(search_query)
        else:
            print("Invalid input")
            return render(request, 'home/home.html', context={})
```

Now inside the app, make a folder named `templates` and add `index.html`

The `index.html` file should look like (to learn more about templates refer to: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/templates/):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <form method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <input type="text" name="search" placeholder="some text"><br>
        <button class="button" name="submit" type="submit">Search</button>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

`my_app/templates/index.html`

Also, if you look at the `<form>` tag, you can find a `method` tag which says `POST`. This indicates whether the data that is being submitted is a `POST` request.

Comment: @Ayann Siddiqui, Thank you, but when I clicked to button I got this error. `CSRF verification failed. Request aborted`. Can you please help me solve this? Thank you again.

Comment: @abby `from django.middleware import csrf` and inside index() `csrf.get_token(request)`

Comment: I still get same error. I have added `csrf.get_token(request)` after `if request.method == 'POST':`, but it didn`t help. Could you show it on sample which you wrote?

Comment: I will get to by the end of the day since I am not on my computer. In the meantime try learning templates, which is what you should use, and then take all the HTML and place it into the template file, and inside the `form` tag add `{% csrf_token %}` which should solve your problem. After which you will not need to use `csrf.get_token`, and your code will look a lot cleaner, because the HTML will be in it's separate file.

Comment: You are getting this error because django requires a csrf token (cross site request forgery) any time you make a `POST` request. Watch this video to learn templating https://youtu.be/SO5t1OjuEaU

Comment: I do not want to be annoying, but I after clicking I have such error: `The view firstapp.views.index didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead`. I have been fixing it for 2 hours, but nothing help me((

Comment: @abby Add a new section to your question and paste all the code in `views.py` and `firstapp/templates/index.html`, and also tell me the path for `views.py` and the `index.html` templates file (Ex: `my_project/blog/views.py`)

Comment: I have edited my question will all needed information. Please, check it. Thank you.

Comment: @abby this is happening because you are not returning anything after setting `search_query` after the for loop try adding `return HttpResponse("Search Works")` it should work after this

Comment: Django requires that you have a return statement in your views. But when we get a successful `POST` request we do not return anything because python does not see any return statements after the `if` block.

Comment: I have added `return HttpResponse("Search Works")` and got `Search Works`, but not get my data from input

Comment: @abby Your input is stored in `search_query` try `return HttpResponse(search_query)` after `if search_query and search_query != "":`

Comment: @abby I've updated my answer `views.py` should have the appropriate return statements.

Comment: it works! but googlesearch doesn`t work. I just can see my input data without googles open. So, I will not be annoying. Thank you very much!

Comment: @abby For the Google Search, you might want to start a new Question. If you have any other questions post them here. Have a nice day